Anypoint Studio v7.19 - Not able to authenticate
I have installed a newly version of Anypoint Studio version 7.19. I am trying to authenticate my account in anypoint platform to anypoint studio. It will just set to blank after I put my login credentials and verification code. Attached are the screenshot for reference.



I have also tried updating the browser to native, update the network to Manual, remove cache and still the issue persist.

Not sure if this is an issue anyone here can help you with. If it is a bug you should report it to MuleSoft. If it is related to network configurations or how the authentication is setup in Anypoint Platform it is off topic here.
